# Windows 10 tablet with duplicated screen forced in portrait mode

Tags: windows, rotation, screen, virtual, tablet

Better than a long description, I made some schemas :)

The 2 native use cases show the classical behaviours when I rotate my tablet.

- [Native Landscape mode use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY3BU.png)
- [Native Portrait mode use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l676Q.png)

Now, I would like to be able to rotate virtualy my tablet and see on the 2nd screen in Portrait mode.
In other words, the tablet remains in landscape with the view rotated 90° and the 2nd screen shows view portrait.

- [Wished behaviour use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3hcQ.png)

But I encountered 2 issues:

1/ The 2nd screen remained in landscape mode with 90° rotation when the "lock rotation" feature is enabled.

- [Behaviour issue when lock rotation enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxm2f.png)

2/ The tablet toggled into lanscape because of autorotation and the 2nd screen stayed in portrait mode but the view is the landscape one.

- [Behaviour issue when lock rotation disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMJoU.png)

So to do that, I found Display.exe to rotate my view and it's a good start.
But it seems that the software is not designed to handle the wished use case.

Is there some extra configuration on Windows 10 to change in order to force duplicated screen to be in portrait mode?

Other ideas to reach my goal are welcome!

Thanks all,

Kelson